# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method

Tags: android, kotlin

while reading the book "Android programming the big nerd ranch guide 4th edition", I ran into the problem that when using `lazy`, the error: `Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable:  public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<QuizViewModel>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): QuizViewModel defined in kotlin`.

```
private val quizViewModel: QuizViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider.(this).get(QuizViewModel::class.java)
}
```

english is not my native language and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so I'm sorry for the mistakes

Comment: This is interesting, on first sight your code looks fine. The only weird part is: `ViewModelProvider.(this)`. You probably meant: `this@ViewModelProvider`. Start by replacing this and let us know if it changed anything.

Comment: It didn't help, but I found the answer on the forum of the authors of the book. [link](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/solution-to-deprecated-method-viewmodelproviders-of/16833/4)